# Server user name and password in nexus Maven setting

Tags: maven, pom.xml, nexus

A default nexus repository manager creates a user name and password pair:

```
user: admin
pass: admin123
```

It works when I log in following the study guide of Sonatype's "exus-evalguide". This is set in nexus-evalguide/maven/settings/settings-localrepo.xm:

```
    <servers>
        <server>
          <id>nexus</id>
          <username>admin</username>
          <password>admin123</password>
        </server>
  </servers>
```

However, I found this username and password doesn't really effect when I run the tutorial by executing:

```
 ./build -f simple-project/pom.xml clean install
```

Why doesn't it effect? Because I purposely change the pair to "admmmin" & "admin1223", the above command still works, execute successfully. So I am wondering what's the purpose of this user name and password.

I am asking this question, because I set up own nexus server and create my own user name and password pair in my settting.xml. For the same reason, I can change the user name and password to anything without affecting the connection of my project to the server.

I am puzzled.

Answer (score 0):

When you will develop your code in corporate then the request will go through the firewall and it will block your request if authentication is not provided.

So that in POM we can provide the **user name** and **Password** to authenticate.

Comment: I am working on my home computer on a Linux CentOS. It should have basic firewall configured I believe. But why my own nexus sever installed in a remote sever also ignore my user/pass setting when I test on a home linux workstation?